# How to describe a process that "isn't adaptable to customization" in fewer words

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to describe that a process isn't adaptable to customization in fewer words.

A full description of the process might be:

> "The entire process is rigid and is only good at doing one thing in a very inefficient manner with little to no capability of being adjusted or adapted to meet simpler requirements run in parallel."

I am hence looking for something along the lines of:

> The process isn't *{adaptable to customization}*

or

> The process is *{not adaptable to customization}*

Comment: Probably "unacceptable" is the word you want.

Comment: the process gets the job done, so it's quite acceptable

but it only does it one way and doesn't care to adapt to simpler or complex tasks (so it will spend same time working on both a simple, normal, and complex task... which creates a problem of not allowing for simple tasks to be expedited and increases the chances of error for the complex tasks)

i'm basically trying to put all that into a  header... and it's tough

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's effectively writing advice

Comment: @Flamoriken - This site has guidelines that we don't re-write sentences for you (as per FumbleFingers's close vote), but we can try to provide words, or phrases, with required meanings; as long as said meanings are well enough described. I *think* your long description fulfils that purpose, as long as you don't want us to rewrite the sentence, but just provide a word to replace the section of your title "isn't adaptable to customization". I've therefore edited your question to suit. If I have misinterpreted, you may revert the edits, but then your question would be likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Would **[inflexible](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inflexible)** work?

> not permitting change or variation; unalterable:

giving:

> The process is *inflexible*

Of course, you could always put in a negative and use **[flexible](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flexible)** instead:

> The process isn't *flexible*

Answer (score 1):

To draw an expression from software development:

> The process is *hardcoded*. You cannot modify it.

Answer (score 0):

The word ***restricted*** may work, especially in a phrase like "*highly **restricted***".

> The process is *(highly) **restricted***.

ODO:

> **[restricted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/restricted)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Limited in extent, number, scope, or action:
>
> ‘Their restricted product line also gives them somewhat limited
>   flexibility.’

Answer (score 0):

How about the word "immutable"

As per Merriam Webster dictionary the definition of immutable is the following -

```
:  not capable of or susceptible to change
```